# Unity Game App asking to make call or access location

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

Im new on Unity game developing and I made a simple game i installed a Admob plugin for ads but it is asking now the user that this app will make calls or access location.

I check the Admob manifest xml and I found this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />
```

I understand that this is nesssary for the ads but Im not sure why my app is asking those information.  Other apps that have ads dont ask for those.

Im not sure if im missing something.. How can I remove the prompt on installation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer the question in case somebody is also having the same problem.

I just commented the following code

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />-->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />-->
  <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />-->
  <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />-->
  <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />-->
```

And admob is still working without these permission and no issues so far.

Comment: You should leave the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. User doesn't care and this will speed up loading, cause of the video buffering